# Swift iOS check if a PythonObject dynamic member is 'callable()'

Tags: python, swift, swift-pythonkit

Im currently porting a Python Script to work in Swift using the PythonKit library, and I'm trying to print out to the console what properties a given PythonObject has.

So I take the following steps to try and work out what dynamic properties a PythonObject has.

```
    let object: PythonObject = SomeObject
    let inspect = Python.import("inspect")
    // Print out the class name of this object
    print(object.__class__.__name__)

    // Get the 'callable' function from python
    let callableFunc = Python.type("callable")

    // List all the properties of the object using the python function __dir__() this equates to just using dir() 
    for fun in object.__dir__()
    {
        // Get the member name
        if let memberName = String(fun)
        {
            // Call the callable function, and convet its return type to a Bool
            if let canCall = Bool(callableFunc(fun))
            {
                // If true then it is callable
                if canCall
                {
                    // NEVER GETS HERE :(
                    // Use the inspect import to check the signature of the function
                    if let params = String(inspect.signature(fun))
                    {
                        // Print some details
                        print(String(memberName) + params)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // ALWAYS GETS HERE
                    // If it fails just print the member name
                    print(memberName)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If it fails just print the member name
                print(memberName)
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in my code example the callable function always fails and says every property is not callable.

Any ideas why this could be? I've read in other posts about something similar in Python if someone calls the 'callable' function using a python function with the parentheses brackets the callable function returns false IE

```
class Pen:
    def write(self):
        print("Writing")

def __call__(self,p):
    print("calling a pen object")

pen1 = Pen()

print(callable(pen1.write())) prints false
print(callable(pen1.write)) prints true
```

Am I missing a trick with the PythonObject in Swift land?